# gmail blocks email sent directly from my app

Tags: android, gmail, jakarta-mail

I am using the JavaMail API to send email directly from my app, but Gmail blocks the sign in attempt saying that it is a 'Less Secure App'. How to deal with this? If in my case, I allowed for my device, then what about other users of my app? Please suggest what should be done. I referred [this tutorial](https://www.oodlestechnologies.com/blogs/Send-Mail-in-Android-without-Using-Intent).

Comment: This may help https://support.google.com/a/answer/6260879?hl=en

Comment: @kiner_shah I looked it, but it is also making one or group of users to allow access to a less secure app. Instead, isn't anything that I can make my app more secure so that Gmail will not block login attempt to any user?

Comment: Use [OAuth2](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/OAuth2).